# ¿Cómo animar en ciclo 2 elementos con CSS3?

Tags: css3, animación

Tengo 2 elementos `<span>` con texto dentro, cuando este completo sean mas, la idea es mostrarlos de a uno en la siguiente loop.

```
loop 
      animacion mostrar elemento 1
      animacion ocultar elemento 1
      animacion mostrar elemento 2
      animacion ocultar elemento 1
```

La animación para mostrarlos no es la gran cosa solo un cambio de opacidad, el problema es que no puedo hacer que la animación funcione de a 1, por ahora tengo lo siguiente

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 32px
}


.item-tag {
    background: #0288D1;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Lato, Roboto, Verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 12px 32px;
    border-radius: 64px;
    
}

.item-0 {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1 {
    animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}



@keyframes bounceIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.1);
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    1% {
        display: inline;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    30% {
        transform: scale(2);
        opacity: 1;
        
    }
    70% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
        <span class="item-tag item-0">
            Item A
        </span>
        <span class="item-tag item-1">
            Item B
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

una opcion seria utilizar `animation-direction: reverse;` que como es claro hace la animacion de atras hacia adelante

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 32px
}


.item-tag {
    background: #0288D1;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Lato, Roboto, Verdana;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 12px 32px;
    border-radius: 64px;
    
}

.item-0 {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1 {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}



@keyframes bounceIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.1);
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    1% {
        display: inline;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    30% {
        transform: scale(2);
        opacity: 1;
        
    }
    70% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
        <span class="item-tag item-0">
            Item A
        </span>
        <span class="item-tag item-1">
            Item B
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: claro pero quiero que se vea un unico elemento a la ves y que cuando termine la animacion del anterior, comience la del siguiente

Comment: Ya es cuestion de que modifiques la animación